# Python Pyautogui returns the wrong coordinates for a object

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

When I try to return an object's coordinates using pyautopgui I always get the wrong coordinates for that object. It returns with the y coordinate as 1090. This is problematic because the element isn't at those coordinates but also because the screen size is only 1920x1080. Is there a fix to this? Link to the site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvbtXv8dy00. I'm trying to get the coordinates for the "SORT BY" button. Thank you!

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Email\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvbtXv8dy00")
time.sleep(3)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)
for item in range(10): 
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))).send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
time.sleep(2)

browser_location = driver.get_window_position()
print(browser_location)

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer/a/paper-button/yt-formatted-string")
position = str(e.location)
x = 1.03*(int((position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0])))
y = 0.73*(int((position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0])))
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 830)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)

for item in range(5): 
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body"))).send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
time.sleep(2)

browser_location = driver.get_window_position()
print(browser_location)

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[1]/span/yt-sort-filter-sub-menu-renderer/yt-dropdown-menu/paper-menu-button/div/paper-button/div")
print(e.location)
position = str(e.location)

print(position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0])
print(position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0])

x = int((position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0]))
y = int((position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0]))

pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)

y = y - 50
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)

time.sleep (5)
```

Update:

```
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.scroll(-750)
time.sleep(2)

x = int((position.split("x': ")[1].split(", 'y':")[0]))
y = int((position.split("'y': ")[1].split("}")[0]))

y = y-500

pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click() 
print("clicked")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: For me the `sortby` is indeed below the actual visual screen. So the coordinates are the absolute coordinates. Try to scroll down first by 100px, and then lower the location by 100.

Comment: Alright! Just had an interesting conversation with another guy. Using `pyautogui.scroll(-750)` to scroll down 750 px. Naturally, you should just then take y-750, right? But then with a bit of testing, I noticed that taking -500 on the y coordinate is perfect.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the second part, but when scrolling down, the coordinates should change in the same way yeah. If both selenium and pyautogui do the same. Also note that there is a click function build into selenium (`element.click()`)

Comment: Alright, but in this case for some reason when scrolling down x pixels isn't the same as the coordinates for the object. Check updated code for.